# Cyberduck alternative for Rackspace

Tags: cloud-storage

I'm looking to upload some files to Rackspace Cloud Files. Basically, I'd like something simple with a GUI like FileZilla.

Rackspace suggests using a program called Cyberduck which does just that, and is compatible with Rackspace's API, but sadly it's not available for linux.

Does anyone know of an alternative I can run on Ubuntu?